# How to control the frame rate in a gstreamer pipeline?

Tags: c, decode, gstreamer, frame-rate

I have astream encoded in 60fps, but my gstreamer pipeline is playing it in fps, so the video appears to be very slow. I have created a gstreamer pipeline as

```
appsrc name=src ! video/x-h264 ! decodebin ! autovideosink sync=false
```

The appsrc will push buffers into the decoder. Now I want to force some frame rate for the video that I am playing. I tried inserting a `videorate` in between `decodebin` and `autovideosink`. But it didnt work. Then I inserted `framerate=30/1` for forcing the framerate as 30fps.. But that also didnt work; So how to force the framerate for the decoder in gstremer pipeline ?

Answer (score 8):

Without seeing the other pipelines you have tried, I came up with this:

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=movie.avi ! decodebin ! \
videorate ! "video/x-raw,framerate=5/1" ! autovideosink
```

movie.avi contains a 30fps video which is then fixed to 5fps before being displayed.

Comment: Would you explain why do we need double quotatopm in framerate parameter?

Comment: I don't think you need them, I just add them.

Comment: Humm...I am confused. Do you mean I need `"video/x-raw,framerate=5/1"` or `video/x-raw,framerate=5/1` is also fine?

Comment: Yes, I think it doesnt matter

Answer (score 0):

As another answer said, add element `videoscale` after `decodebin` and add capfilter to specify framerate.

Add property `max-rate` to `videoscale` works as well.

```bash
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=movie.avi ! decodebin ! \
videorate max-rate=5 ! autovideosink
```